# What's the default username/password for a PostgreSQL server in Rails 4?

Tags: postgresql

I've looked all over the internet and nobody seems to have this answer.

I've never created a user, am I supposed to?

"root" and "password" throws up "password authentication failed" and leaving the fields blank throws up "no password supplied"

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Did you try with `postgres` as username and password ?

Comment: I had to read this several times before I realized what you meant, but yes. The default username and password are "postgres" and "password".

Comment: Also when you set a superuser password during PostgreSQL installation, the password may be set up to this "superuser password" value (at least happened for me with the windows-installer installation).

Comment: This is not the default.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an older version of Chocolatey, the default user is `postgres` or `postgresql` and default password is `Postgres1234`

As of Feb, 2023 (and perhaps earlier), Chocolatey will generate a password for you and display it when you run the install (see logs if you're using the GUI), or you can specify one in the install command:

```
choco install -y postgresql --params '/Password:test'
```

There are other options, see the [Chocolatey docs](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/postgresql)

Comment: That has changed last time I had to install via chocolatey. The default user is still 'postgres', but choco generates a random password for you.

Comment: how can i recover the choco postgresql password for postgres user

Comment: Updated answer to reflect change. @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz that should be a question by itself

Comment: I had to unnistall and reinstall.